# Cache picsum images with azure CDN

Tags: azure, caching, cdn, azure-cdn

I created an ad hoc application to test the azure cache features to study for the az204. 
It is a simple node application in app service that renders a large image using [lorem picsum](https://picsum.photos/).

`<img src="https://picsum.photos/2000" style="width: 100%;">`

I created a [Standard Azure CDN Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-caching-rules) and added the Endpoint.
Then Set the global rule to be override with Always Cache expiration 30 min.

**Expected Result**:
From this moment I expected my application to cache the image, witch means that when I reload the page accessing from the CDN's url I should get the **same image** as before for at least 30 minute.

**Actual Result**:
But the actual result is that when I load the page it is loading always a **different image** as it would without a cdn.

I also tried by creating a new rule for image type jpeg override 30 min, but It didn't worked.

How can I return a cached image from lorem picsum using the Frontdoor Azure Standard Cache CDN?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment, If you are trying to access Azure CDN caching rules to cache expiration duration the condition passes though the storage blob files.

I have created front door CDN profile endpoint and added caching behavior override like below:

[image]

This cache rule applies for your storage container file like below:

[image]

In storage container -> files. This files we can access through url and Override and Set if missing caching behavior.

```
https://lorem.azureedge.net/container1/lorem pic 1.jpg
```

Set TTL as 86400 or 1-day cache control  **`Cachecontrol="public,max-age=86400"`**

> **Changing the cache duration while accessing the  url *lorem picsum* is not possible**

When you check front door designer these are the different cache behaviors which can be implemented at different edge.

[image]

***References***:

[Azure Storage Azure Front Door Azure CDN](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/azure-on-the-cheap-azure-front-door-caching-vs-azure-cdn/ba-p/1372262)

[Integrate Caching And CDNs Within Solutions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/road-to-az-204-integrate-caching-and-content-delivery-within-solutions/)  by *Thiago Vivas*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and effort reproducing that.
The example is a little different anyway, **I don't have a storage account**, in the example I use a service api that returns **random images** of a certain resolution via img src=...

I expect the first image that is shown to be cached and returned until the TTL expires. 
The same as if you put a **random number** in the page and I expect the cache to **return the same** random generated on the **first time**.